# casperjs click not selector but variable

Tags: javascript, click, casperjs

Is it possible to click page element in casper js without passing selector? I mean I can't do that:

```
casperjs.thenClick('#test');
```

But I have

```
var testV = document.querySelector('#test');
```

And I want do something like this:

```
casperjs.thenClick(testV);
```

For now it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [thenClick](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#thenclick) improperly.  Make sure the then.click is not contained within a casper.evaluate block and note there is not the `js` on the end of casper.  It should be implemented as:

```
casper.thenClick('a', function() {
    this.echo("I clicked on first link found, the page is now loaded.");
});
```

If you want to just perform a regular [click](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#click) on selector you can do the following:

```
casper.then(function() {
    // Click on 1st result link
    this.click('h3.r a');
});
```

If you would like to use javascript, make sure you are within a [casper.evaluate](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate) statement.  You can use the following:

```
casper.then(function() {
    casper.evaluate(function() {
        var testV = document.getElementById("test");
        testV.click();
    });
});
```

Comment: ok 'casperjs' was mistake only when I type that here. In my code it was ok :) But the rest still doesn't work.

Comment: Please mark my answer as a correct answer and I am reviewing your code from question: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20243033/2812723)

Comment: I've tested it and first doesn't work. But I test this on other site and it work. It work on input submit, but it doesn't on anchor. So your solution is good, but not perfect :) any idea what with anchors ?