# casperjs and phantomjs hang on casper.start no timeout no error

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I have been running a casperjs/phantomjs script on my ubuntu 12.04 server for many months without issue.  Suddenly it has stopped.  There have been no configuration changes (that I know of).

Even testing the simple script posted here, casperjs just hangs on casper.start.  No errors are reported and it does not time out.  I have also tried running it with the --ingore-ssl-errors=true flag with the same result.

I do not know where to look for errors and logs to begin to troubleshoot this.

Sample script I'm trying:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://casperjs.org/', function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.thenOpen('http://phantomjs.org', function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.run();
```

Comment: I doubt this is it, but what about `--ssl-protocol=tlsv1`?

Comment: Well stop doubting because that worked!  The only thing I can think of is that the host did some mandatory SSL upgrade/patch that kocked my stuff offline.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CasperJS/PhantomJS doesn't load https page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26415188/casperjs-phantomjs-doesnt-load-https-page)

Comment: @ArtjomB. You should write that as an answer to get some upvotes.

Comment: @EmilStenström No, I shouldn't. This is a duplicate. It's frowned upon to answer duplicate questions.