# Unknown option when using CasperJS with "--ssl-protocol=tlsv1 --engine=slimerjs"

Tags: ssl, phantomjs, casperjs, slimerjs

Every since the sslv3 POODLE bug came out I am unable to use casperjs with the "--engine=slimerjs" option.

Before POODLE I was able to run my casperjs script like this:

```
casperjs --engine=slimerjs script.js
```

But after POODLE I needed to also send the "--ssl-protocol=tlsv1" to casperjs.  This works without using the slimer option like this:

```
casperjs --ssl-protocol=tlsv1 script.js
```

Now if I want to use the slimerjs engine and send the ssl-protocol like this:

```
casperjs --ssl-protocol=tlsv1 --engine=slimerjs script.js
```

it fails with:

```
unknown option --ssl-protocol=tlsv1
```

How can I use casperjs with slimerjs with the "--ssl-protocol=tlsv1" option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is resolved from SlimerJS 0.9.5 onwards and supports full compatibility with PhantomJS 2 for this case. See [this commit](https://github.com/laurentj/slimerjs/commit/fd2d63ae29f8d821397aef4368d278ce4ed89840).

---

Previous answer:

The [docs](http://docs.slimerjs.org/current/configuration.html) say it is unsupported and since SSL is so low-level, there is probably not even a workaround besides waiting for a new version of slimerjs (current version 0.9.3).

> –ssl-protocol=[SSLv3|SSLv2|TLSv1|any]  Unsupported     Firefox supports only the SSL 3 protocol

The bottom line is that SlimerJS is now unusable on all sites that removed SSLv3 support. This is the general SlimerJS issue: [Support of SSL options](https://github.com/laurentj/slimerjs/issues/26).

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up.  I hope slimerjs updates!  I finally get my code working a couple of weeks ago then this damn POODLE bug comes along :(

Comment: Want to set ssl-protocol to tlsv1 
Working for phantomjs but not for casperjs
phantomjs --ssl-protocol=tlsv1 sslCheck.js

casperjs --ssl-protocol=tlsv1 test MQR15BVT_LoadTesting.js


Am I doing anything wrong !