# casperjs cannot open https url

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

Running test on Windows 7

In casperjs i tried to open my **https** page as below:

```
...
var Link1 = 'https://mylink1.com/';
casper.waitForSelector("input#KeyField", function() {
        console.log(Link1);
        this.sendKeys('input#KeyField', Link1 );
    });
casper.then(function() {
        this.echo(this.getTitle());
        this.capture(dir1 + 'image1.png', {
            top: 0, left: 0, width: 2000, height: 1000
            });
        });
...
```

Casperjs will not open the link, **but using "http" for same page from my local, it simply works.**

Then I have tried stuff like:

- casperjs test mytest1.js --ignore-ssl-errors=true --ssl-protocol=tlsv1
- casperjs test mytest1.js --web-security=no
- casperjs test mytest1.js--ssl-protocol=any
- casperjs test mytest1.js --ignore-ssl-errors=yes
- casperjs --ignore-ssl-errors test mytest1.js

still, casperjs could not open it. any ideas pls.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CasperJS/PhantomJS doesn't load https page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26415188/casperjs-phantomjs-doesnt-load-https-page)

Comment: yes it helped for sure. it's a known bug from phantomjs, i upgraded already to 1.9.8. thanks

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
casperjs test mytest1.js --ignore-ssl-errors=true
```