# Basic Authentication with CasperJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs, basic-authentication

Casperjs has some issue as it's not authenticating page when loaded initially, below is my code.

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
  verbose: false,
  logLevel: 'debug',
  pageSettings: {
    loadImages: false, // The WebPage instance used by Casper will
    loadPlugins: false, // use these settings
  }
});

// print out all the messages in the headless browser context
casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
  this.echo('remote message caught: ' + msg);
});

// print out all the messages in the headless browser context
casper.on("page.error", function(msg, trace) {
  this.echo("Page Error: " + msg, "ERROR");
});

//casper.options.viewportSize = {width: 1366, height: 667};

casper.start();
casper.options.pageSettings = {
  customHeaders:{
    'Authorization':'Basic '+btoa('username:password')
  }
}

casper.thenOpen('https://www.dmr.nd.gov/oilgas/basic/getwellprod.asp', function(status) {
  if (status !== 'success') {
    console.log('Unable to access network');
  } else {
    console.log("Getting Authenticated");
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
  }
});

casper.run();
```

I also tried using setHttpAuth with no luck. Here the Phantom version and resource.error message - Phantom version is 1.9.2 and ErrorCode is 6 and description is SSL handshake failed

Comment: Acutally i have used the casper.capture() but it's a blank image..

Comment: So here it is sir, Phantom version is 1.9.2 and ErrorCode is 6 and description is SSL handshake failed

Comment: possible duplicate of [CasperJS/PhantomJS doesn't load https page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26415188/casperjs-phantomjs-doesnt-load-https-page)

Comment: So if i upgrade to Phantom 2 there seems to be problem with the CasperJs , and i did change the version function in bootstrap.js but still the same issue. Also i did try what you said in other post to use 'any' but it didn't work in this context

Comment: I use CasperJS from the github master branch and it works flawlessly with PhantomJS 2, but you don't *need* to update. Just use the commandline options. I updated my answer.

Comment: Still no luck with the command line options

Comment: What is the new output that you see (terminal&screenshot)?

Answer (score 2):

#### POODLE

The error message from the `resource.error` suggests that it is a POODLE bug. PhantomJS < 1.9.8 uses SSLv3 by default, but because of POODLE many web servers disabled SSLv3 support. So you need to tell PhantomJS/CasperJS that TLS should be used:

```
--ssl-protocol=tlsv1
```

You can also throw `--ignore-ssl-errors=true` in for good measure.

More information here: [CasperJS/PhantomJS doesn't load https page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26415188/casperjs-phantomjs-doesnt-load-https-page)

#### Basic Auth

There is no `customHeaders` option for [`pageSettings`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#pagesettings). You probably meant to use the PhantomJS' [`customHeaders`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/custom-headers.html) option:

```
casper.page.customHeaders:{
    'Authorization': 'Basic '+btoa('username:password')
};
```

A better way would be to use the appropriate settings for this:

```
casper.options.pageSettings = {
    userName: username,
    password: password
};
```

You can also define this during creation.

If this doesn't solve your problem, check with the `resource.requested` and `resource.received` events whether the headers are set.

#### Callback arguments

Another issue with your code is that there is no `status` for the callback of `thenOpen` and other step functions. The last successfully loaded resource object is passed into the callback and not a string. So you cannot detect whether the page was loaded successfully using that.

Comment: Has my answer helped? I forgot to ping you after adding the POODLE remark.