# Does SpookyJS support https web pages?

Tags: javascript, testing, phantomjs, casperjs, spookyjs

I'm new to SpookyJS.
In the hello.js example which has been provided i tried changing the url

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spooky_the_Tuff_Little_Ghost

to

> https://www.twitter.com/

or

> www.facebook.com with https

none of these seem to be opening.

PhantomJS version is 1.9.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be very well related the POODLE problem of PhantomJS. ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26419531/1816580)) It is usually fixed by passing `--ssl-protocol=tlsv1` and possibly `--ignore-ssl-errors=true` on the commandline.

Judging by [issue #81](https://github.com/WaterfallEngineering/SpookyJS/issues/81), you can do this in SpookyJS:

```
var spooky = new Spooky({
  capser: {
    logLevel: "debug",
    verbose: true
  },
  child: {
    command: "casper",
    "ssl-protocol": "tlsv1",
    "ignore-ssl-errors": true
  }
});
```

You may also want to update PhantomJS. This is fixed in 1.9.8 and later, but CasperJS doesn't currently (1.1-beta3) support PhantomJS 2. Either use the master branch of CasperJS which does support PhantomJS 2 or stick to 1.9.8.

Comment: Thanks you,Updating PhantomJS helped me.Where can i find more SpookyJS examples?