# casperjs and https still not working

Tags: https, casperjs

Ok guys, we've been working on this for a while now(many days).  I have seen and tried all the documentation on the "casperjs --ignore-ssl-errors=yes test4.js".  We have tried every scenario on the net regarding the https issue but nothing is working.  Tests are working on our local host but when we run the test on the https servers we are getting an about:blank null return on te https status.  Again casperjs --ignore-ssl-errors=yes test4.js and all other combinations are not fixing the problem.  Are we overlooking something?  Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [CasperJS/PhantomJS doesn't load https page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26415188/casperjs-phantomjs-doesnt-load-https-page)

Answer (score 0):

You may also need `--ssl-protocol=any` in arguments.