# Casperjs/Phantomjs does not respect hosts file

Tags: javascript, testing, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to run tests against my vagrant box with lives at 192.168.0.100. In my hosts file I have 192.168.0.100 lc.mysite.com and the site loads fine and works normally at that url with chrome.

However, when I try and run my tests against it, the url fails and never loads anything. Remote urls work fine but the local ones are just failing.

How can I get casperjs to respect my hosts file? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a self-signed SSL certificate (e.g. on your development box), set phantomjs option

`--ignore-ssl-errors=true`

From the documentation:

`--ignore-ssl-errors     Ignores SSL errors (expired/self-signed certificate errors): 'true' or 'false' (default)`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was due to the url being ssl and it kept failing. Using this answer solved my issue.

[CasperJS/PhantomJS failing SSL handshakes on some sites even with --ssl-protocol=any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29441151/casperjs-phantomjs-failing-ssl-handshakes-on-some-sites-even-with-ssl-protocol)