# codeception phantomjs sslv3

Tags: phantomjs, sslv3

I used phantomjs for my acceptence test in php project. But phantomjs returns blank page when i redirect to other page. Output of resposnse is

configuration of my acceptance.suite.yml is

> > class_name: AcceptanceTester
> >     modules:

```
enabled:
    - \Helper\Acceptance
    - WebDriver
config:
    WebDriver:
        browser: phantomjs
        acceptSslCerts: true
        url: http://mysite.dev
        host: 127.0.0.1
        port: 4444
        wait: 5
        window_size: 1400x1000
        capabilities:
            unexpectedAlertbehavior: "accept"
            sslProtocal: "any"
            ignoreSslErrors: "true"
            webSecurity: "false"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021578/phantomjs-failing-to-open-https-site

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26415188/casperjs-phantomjs-doesnt-load-https-page