# casperjs failed to access certain websites that even wget can

Tags: web-scraping, wget, casperjs

A very simple example link https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/daf/index.cfm.

Even wget without any header information can successfully scrape the information.

However, casperjs just not work

```
var casper=require("casper").create();
var mouse=require("mouse").create(casper);
var link="https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/daf/index.cfm";
casper.start().then(function() {
        this.open(link);
        this.wait(5000);  
});
casper.run(function(){
        this.echo(this.getPageContent()).exit();
});
```

It always output

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

add header info does not help, like below

```
this.open(link, {
                method: 'get',
                authority: 'www.accessdata.fda.gov',
                path: '/scripts/cder/daf/index.cfm',
                scheme: 'https',
                headers: {
                        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36',
                        'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
                        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
                        'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,zh-TW;q=0.8,zh;q=0.7,zh-CN;q=0.6,ja;q=0.5',
                        'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
                        'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
                        'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
                        'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
                        'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
                        'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1'
                    
                }
        });
```

I tried many combinations of header style but just not work.

However, it is noteworthy that the casperjs code above works for certain website like http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/selectors.html

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that add --ssl-protocol=any

```
casperjs --ssl-protocol=any yourScript.js
```

solved the issue

this link has more explanation
[CasperJS/PhantomJS doesn't load https page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26415188/casperjs-phantomjs-doesnt-load-https-page)