# Running phantomjs/casperjs native option in script that is launched with Python

Tags: python, bash, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

CasperJS version 1.1.0-beta3, using phantomjs version 1.9.8 along with Python 2.7.6 on OSX 10.10.4 64-bit.

Hello and thanks for stoping by :)

I'm running a JS script, using casperjs, that needs to be launched with a Python script.

When launched from bash the JS script needs the CLI `--ignore-ssl-errors=true`to run successfully.

When launching the Python script in bash it is not possible to use `--ignore-ssl-errors=true`since it is a phantomjs/casperjs native option. To work around this I tried to do it programatically as it seemed possible according to the comments for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20243033/run-phantomjs-with-ignore-ssl-errors-true-from-casperjs).

After reading [this](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11775) I used the following syntax combinations in my JS script:

```
ignoreSslErrors : true;

ignoreSslErrors = true;

ignoreSslErrorsEnabled : true;

ignoreSslErrorsEnabled = true;
```

None worked when launching the JS script, so it would not work when the script
is launched with the Python script. Did I miss something in my syntax?

Is there a way to send a native command to phantomjs/casperjs through a Python script? To be specific, is there a way to send `--ignore-ssl-errors=true` through the Python script?

Please let me know if you need further details.

Thank you for taking the time to read :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*> When launching the Python script in bash it is not possible to use --ignore-ssl-errors=true*

Actually, it's quite possible. This way works fine:

```
import subprocess
args = ['/usr/local/bin/casperjs', '--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '/path/to/script.js']
subprocess.call(args)
```

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thank you :) I have to level up my Python game :D